# Can we download HTML page when file menubar is disabled in IE7?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, download

I need to download an HTML page from a website. But the page opens in a new window with no menu bar. I need to gets CSS, JS and Image resources while downloading. If I do view the source and save it, its media content is not getting downloaded.

Any idea if we can do it in IE7? The site is not opening in Firefox/Chrome.

Comment: You wrote "its media content are getting downloaded".

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you only want the HTML contents. In that case you can View Source and copy and paste the HTML into a text editor like Notepad.

If you want to download the other resources associated with the HTML file, manually download them by accessing the URI of the resource itself (they should be present in the HTML, look for attributes `href` and `src` (in the case of `<object>`, look for the `data` attribute).

Another option would be to install the [IE Developer Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=18359) for IE7 and get the URIs of the resources there, or upgrade to [Internet Explorer 8](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/download-ie) and use the built-in developer tools to monitor the resources that are downloaded via the Network panel.

Comment: "I need to gets CSS, JS and Image resource while downloading."

Comment: Set in the copy a base tag and this works ;)

Comment: @Juhana Edited.

Answer (score 0):

[wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) is [available for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) and will handle your task and more, look for the [--mirror option](http://fosswire.com/post/2008/04/create-a-mirror-of-a-website-with-wget/) and Bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your page, choose properties, copy the URL and paste it in a new IE window (with a menu). You should then be able to "Save as". Unless your page is built based on posted values, this should work.